# XMLDocument Class - Child Nodes - Abbreviated Load versus Full Load

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am exploring the XMLDocument Class

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

I am using the above site to type in examples.  I typed in the example to get child nodes and it works.  My question is why doesn't it work when I use the full XML document that contains 
 along more than one book added.  What about the code needs to be modified to make it work when I use it with a full XML Document.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<book ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
                "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
                "<price>19.95</price>" +
                "</book>");

    XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;

    //Display the contents of the child nodes.
    if (root.HasChildNodes)
    {
      for (int i=0; i<root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(root.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
      }
    }
```

The full XML Load that I am using is below. It was copied from
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 doc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> \n" +
"<books xmlns=\"http://www.contoso.com/books\"> \n" +
"<book genre=\"novel\" ISBN=\"1-861001-57-8\"publicationdate=\"1823-01- 
  28\">\n"+
"    <title>Pride And Prejudice</title> \n" +
"    <price>24.95</price> \n" +
"  </book> \n" +
"<book genre=\"novel\" ISBN=\"1-861002-30-1\"ublicationdate=\"1985-01- 
  01\">\n" +
"    <title>The Handmaid's Tale</title> \n" +
"    <price>29.95</price> \n" +
"  </book> \n" +
"</books>");
```

Comment: Could you please add sample full XML document, expected output and actual output or errors to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since first node is `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, the books are not in `doc.FirstChild` but in `doc.DocumentElement;`

```
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
```

In your sample xml, the root of the document is `book` and child nodes are `title` and `price`. But if you want to have multiple `books` each child node is a `book`, not a `title` or `price`, so you need to access those by name or iterate to get the next level.

```
foreach(XmlNode book in root)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}\r\nPrice: {1}", 
        book["title"].InnerText,
        book["price"].InnerText);
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
foreach (XmlNode book in root)
{
    foreach (XmlNode attribute in book)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(attribute.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run my code and check the value of (root.HasChildNodes) it is reflecting false when I run against the Full XMLLoad that has the ?xmlversion header

Comment: I have edited my answer. If your xml has `<?xmlversion header>` you can't use `doc.FirstChild` because it's going to get above header instead of the root.